# How to implement partial class in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-classes

I have a class **Employee.cs** that was autogenerated by EntityFramework when i connected to a database, now i want to implement a **partial class** but I can't use "Employee.cs" name for that class because it already exists. Can I give **other name** to it and it will work? Can you explain how the compiler will know that there is another partial class of Employee.cs?

Comment: Note that in C#, unlike Java, the name of the file does not have to match the name of the class, so you can put the other declarations in any file and the compiler will find it when it scans the files that are part of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the file whatever name you want like **Employee.custom.cs** but you have to call the class in it **Employee** in the same namespace as the Employee class in the other file, also with a `partial` modifier, and you should be good to go.

The compiler just gathers all the `partial` classes with the same name and compiles it into one class per name.

Comment: But the Employee class is auto generated right. He should not take the route of adding a partial keyword there.. right?

Comment: @Reddy EF code-first should generate partial classes by default.

Comment: Ok that makes sense . Thanks Stanley

Answer (score 2):

Compiler always works with fullname of class. If there is a project named MyProject, full name for the class would be something like:

```
MyProject.Employee
```

If You want to create class with the same name, You have to add a level of separation in naming, or if it have to be partial class with this generated class, You have to mark it also as a partial.

You can either create (in *Model/Employee.cs*):

```
public class MyProject.AnySubPath.Employee {}
```

Or:

In file *Model/Employee.cs*

```
public partial class MyProject.Employee {}
```

In file *ViewModel/Employee.cs*

```
public partial class MyProject.Employee {}
```

Important for You is to realize what is the partial mean & what will the compiler to with Your class: In fact the compiler will just put all the `partial` classes together and then compile them. Only benefit from being `partial` is that You can have the code split among multiple files. Excelent example for this is `Windows.Forms`, where You have "code-behind" file (Form1.cs) and then You have "designer" file (Form1.Designer.cs).

Also You can name the files whatever name You want, it is just common standard to have 1 class = 1 file and the class name should fit the file name.